# How to monitor/access my pc using my android phone?

Tags: windows, display, android, remote

Sometimes I leave my PC for hours, rendering and I need to know how to monitor it, maybe access it from my phone to send an email or something, is that possible?

Comment: What are you using to render ?

Answer (score 1):

Find an RDP or VNC client for Android there are heaps available.

That will solve the problem of accessing it if you are "in range of your home PC".   If you are wanting to do this when you are outside your network you will also need to set up either port forwarding on your router (and know your home systems IP address), or set up a VPN to get you onto your home network.

Comment: Teamviewer is also there.